# Django множественный ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

Изучаю Django, решил написать совою систему комментариев. Создал несколько моделей различных типов материалов:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.datetime.now, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.datetime.now, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Теперь делаю модель комментария:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    material = models.ForeignKey(?????)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.datetime.now, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Вопрос: как поле material сделать множественным, что бы можно было привязать комментарий как к Post, так и к Question?

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, вроде бы разобрался. Если не прав, то поправьте.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.datetime.now, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

В admin.py соответственно:

```
class CommentInline(GenericTabularInline):
    model = Comment

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'date', 'author')
    inlines = [
        CommentInline,
    ]

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'date', 'author')
    inlines = [
        CommentInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

Ну и для удобства можно добавить:

```
class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('text', 'date', 'author', 'content_type', 'object_id', 'content_object')

admin.site.register(Comment, CommentAdmin)
```

Пример нашел тут https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

Вот тут все неплохо описано. Немного хитрее чем с обычным полем но доступно.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка.

Comment: Не могу согласиться с комментарием по двум причинам

 - Ответ на этот вопрос выжимкой дать невозможно, он достаточно сложен и требует понимания принципов работы  Contenttypes framework, которые описаны по приведенной ссылке.
 - Это ссылка на сайт с официальной документацией и вероятность иземнения или протухания ссылки ничтожна мала

Comment: @VladimirAbramov В двух словах в общих деталях добавить объяснение всё равно не повредит.